# iOS - pass Array error as parameters using AFNetworking library

Tags: ios, arrays, api, post, raw-data

I'm new in iOS.

I pass array in JSON as a request but I didn't get response, it works fine in a Postman

[I use this api check this url - check it first](https://www.detrack.com/api-documentation/view-vehicles/)

Here is my code where I pass array as a request:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

    //RequestSerializer
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:Detrack_Key forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-API-KEY"];

    //ResponseSerializer
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer=[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];

    //create JSON String
    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData2 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arr options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"jsonData as string:\n%@", jsonString);


    NSLog(@"URL: %@",strUrl);
```

Request :

```
[
   "DriverFirst",
   "DriverSecond"
]
```

I want to know only how to pass row json array request?

Comment: you should send your json data against a key. i have not found any key in you json

Comment: you need to convert array in json array and than pass array with key

Comment: yes i have a key i  pass key in header

Comment: @IOS - actually i have idea  form data but i need to pass in row data , i have no idea about row data please help

Comment: where you have dashboard key?

Comment: **Detrack_Key** i store in this variable

Comment: how to pass row json array request?

Comment: what you are getting in this log NSLog(@"jsonData as string:\n%@", jsonString); ?